# Windows 8.1: How to ascertain 'true' uptime?

Tags: windows-8, uptime

Please read carefully; this is not the usual uptime question.

I tend not to *shut down* my computer per se but instead put it to sleep. It makes boot times quicker and allows me to use WOL. The various 'uptime' methods (sysinfo, uptime.exe, Task Manager, etc) will show the time since the last full boot, which means time spent sleeping is factored in. I am looking for *true* uptime; that is, only the time since the last boot my PC has spent awake.

Comment: Sleep/ wake/ shutdown events are all logged in the system event log. You could probably do some calculations using the times of these events. I'm not going to attempt to try and write it for you though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no software that does this, so the only way you would be able to do this is by writing a script that basically gives a variable a +1 every second (or minute), and have a way to read the value of the variable. If your PC is in hibernation/sleep/etc., the script is not running, thus the counter is not increased.

It is likely going to impact the system if such script is constantly running in the background, so the question is, how badly do you want this?

(reason for impact on the script) the longer the script runs, the higher the number becomes, and a value that is really high means it needs more memory to store. (talking about values that cannot be integers (65535), but I suppose that if you go this high, your system must be up and running for days/weeks. Of course, you could write your script to count days and reset the value which would eliminate that, but if then your script is going through more code in its cycle which on itself is also going to impact it, even if little.

Comment: Solid answer, thanks. Shame this isn't catered for natively though.

Comment: How much storage do you expect it to need?  2³² seconds is 136 years.  2³² minutes is, obviously, 60 times as much (over 8160 years).

Answer (score 1):

Windows generates a system event for waking from sleep (Event ID: 1, Source: Power-Troubleshooter).  This event contains the sleep and wake times.

[image: Wake Event]

Source: [Wake Source - Read Event Viewer Log - Windows 7 Help Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/179257-wake-source-read-event-viewer-log.html)

To determine your "true uptime" value, determine the last boot time (from the sources you mentioned) then subtract the time spent sleeping from any subsequent wake events.

Note: You can create an application to query the Event Log using .NET libraries (off-topic on Super User).

Comment: (1) While this link may answer the question, it is better to include a more detailed description of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become nearly useless if your link goes down.  (2) You seem to be suggesting a GUI interface to a heap of raw data.  Are you suggesting that the user manually transcribe all the sleep/wake event times since the last boot into a calculator and then crunch the numbers him/herself to get the total time that (s)he is looking for?  Or do you know of some way that a script can access these data?

Comment: See simplified answer.

Answer (score 0):

How flexible are you in your definition of “true uptime”? 
A variation on [LPChip’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/942055/150988)
is to write Scheduled Tasks that are triggered by Workstation Lock
and Workstation Unlock, and then do the obvious math.

And, in case the math isn’t obvious:

1. Keep track of two values: “logical” boottime and cumulative uptime. 
   Only one of these will be valid at a time. 
   So, arguably, you also need a flag to keep track of which of them is valid,
   although this can practically be determined by context.
2. I guess you would also want an event that runs at system boot,
   or have some other mechanism to initialize
   the “logical” boottime to the actual boottime.
3. When the workstation is locked,
   subtract the logical boottime from the current time
   and save this as the cumulative uptime.
4. When the workstation is unlocked,
   subtract the cumulative uptime from the current time
   and save this as the logical boottime.
5. Upon request,
   subtract the logical boottime from the current time
   and report this as the “true” uptime. 
   (This will give you the total amount of time that the PC has been unlocked.)

So, for example,

1. If you do a hard boot at 9 AM, this saves 9 AM as the logical boottime.
2. If you lock the machine at noon,
   this saves 3 hours (noon − 9 AM) as the cumulative uptime.
3. If you unlock the machine at 1 PM,
   this saves 10 AM (1 PM − 3 hours) as the logical boottime.
4. If you ask for uptime at 6 PM, this reports 8 hours
   (6 PM − 10 AM = (noon − 9 AM) + (6 PM − 1 PM).)

If you can figure out how to trigger tasks to run on sleep and wake,
then do that, and it’ll get you exactly what you asked for. 
(But putting the machine to sleep will trigger the Lock task,
and I assume that you have your system configured to require unlock after wake.)

Comment: I'd like to emphrase that you indeed need to calculate the uptime once on these events, and not start a script that runs in the background through scheduled task or you will encounter some serious performance issues. I wrote a script that would do some simple math as a scheduled task, and if this script was running, I could not play a game and record it with fraps as I would experience lag. When I hadn't run this scheduled task, it was all fine. And strangely enough, if I manually ran the script then played my game and recorded with fraps, it was fine too.